# Windows Phone. How to use large database?

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have dictionary Windows Phone project. I need to run search by substring in different table (13000 — 29000 entries). Now have SQLite DB File and SDF.

SQLite is really slow when using substring search (about 4 sec). But it has async methods.
SQL CE is faster (~500 ms). But there is no async methods for it (i need in ~10 queries per one search).

How to improve speed? It's needed only SELECT queries.

Comment: I'm no expert in WP, but could you wrap the SQL CE in a async method? thus you would get the faster speed, and the program would not freeze.

Comment: Do you have indexes in your DB?

Comment: @x2. Yes, i have indexes.

Comment: @ChristianSauer I didn't find the way to do it :(

Comment: @maximbazhanov it is not that hard, just create a async method which executes Task.run(() => DbCE.NotAsyncMethood());.

Comment: @x2 and do you have indexes that help for _LIKE "%foo%"_ ?

Comment: @x2.I'm not sure what is it :(

Comment: @ChristianSauer How to use inputs variables for this?

Comment: @maximbazhanov could you describe your question a little bit more?

Comment: @ChristianSauer My function looks like "DB.Search(string text)". Can use it like this "await Task.Run(() => DB.Search(textBox.text))"? Or it will be cross-thread access exception?

Comment: @maximbazhanov no you cannot do that. But you can very easily store the textBox.text to a intermediate varible before running the task.

Comment: @maximbazhanov No problem :) Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: @ChristianSauer if you want)